# cannot return reference to temporary value but everything is 'static

Tags: rust, reference, static

I am trying to instantiate a struct from static values. The compiler says that I am creating a temporary value but everything is referenced and static. I found [this github issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/69574) and it looks like my problem.

```rust
struct OutputDescription {
    name: &'static str,
}

struct SubOutput<T> {
    sub_param_a: T,
}

struct Output {
    param_a: SubOutput<bool>
}

impl <T: Description>Description for SubOutput<T> {
    fn name() -> &'static str {
        "param_a"
    }

    fn fields() -> &'static [OutputDescription] {
        &[OutputDescription {
            name: T::name(),
        }]
    }
}

trait Description {
    fn name() -> &'static str;

    fn fields() -> &'static [OutputDescription];
}
```

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0515]: cannot return reference to temporary value
  --> src/main.rs:19:9
   |
19 |            &[OutputDescription {
   |   _________^-
   |  |_________|
   | ||
20 | ||             name: T::name(),
21 | ||         }]
   | ||          ^
   | ||__________|
   |  |__________returns a reference to data owned by the current function
   |             temporary value created here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0515`.
error: could not compile `playground` (bin "playground") due to previous error
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=68ec8292d5306c3ea380148c0bc1613a)

I am looking for a fix or a workaround if this is a compiler issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call a trait function at compile-time, so it's not possible to construct a static value by calling a trait function. But since your functions have no parameters, you can use `const`s instead of `fn`s:

```rust
trait Description {
    const NAME: &'static str;

    const FIELDS: &'static [OutputDescription];
}

impl<T: Description> Description for SubOutput<T> {
    const NAME: &'static str = "param_a";

    const FIELDS: &'static [OutputDescription] = &[OutputDescription { name: T::NAME }];
}
```

Of course, this prohibits implementations whose return values are not constants.

Comment: Just as I finish [my resolution](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c65c6c62a7246d7a50a7b7c9e562ac73) to the more advanced example of OP below you come in with this.

Comment: i did some testing and i think thats exactly what i want, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
[OutputDescription {
    name: T::name(),
}]
```

is a temporary, if it can be promoted to a constant—and therefore if you can take a static reference to it—depends on several factors, calling a function like `T::name` [prevents it](https://github.com/rust-lang/const-eval/issues/19), thus you don't get constant promotion and thus you can't return a static reference to it.

Comment: thanks for this workaround, looks promising. i used it to create a more complex implementation but now i do not understand why the second field is not u32.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9fdc1ec8597c43e329cdadf18adbb0ba

both are bool but the second generic should be u32 because of 
`name: SubOutput::<u32>::name()` ?

Comment: Ah my bad, the static is shared across implementations, thus the first call initializes it, and the second just returns what was stored in the first, in that case I'm not sure there is a workaround.